# Measure Theory question regarding Definition

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

In measure theory, the definition goes like this. " Let $f$ be a function on $[a,b]$. We say that $f$ is a measurable function if, for every $s \in \Bbb R$, the set $\{x: f(x)>s\}$ is a measurable set".
My Question is, If I consider $A = \{x: f(x)>s\}$, then whether $A = (s,b)$ or $(s, \infty)$. please explain in detail. If Possible give some examples taking [a,b] = [2,5].

Comment: How do you claim $A=(s,b)$ or $(s, \infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X,m)$ be a measure space. A function $f$: $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be measurable iff {$x: f(x)> s$} is measurable for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$. More importantly the set {$x: f(x)> s$} is not $(s,\infty)$ but the inverse image of $(s,\infty)$, $f^{-1}(s,\infty)$.

If $f$ is bounded, then there exists some $b \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $|f(x)| < b$. In that case, {$x: f(x)> s$}=$f^{-1}(s,b)$

Comment: The set $A$ is a subset of the domain of $f$ whereas $f(x)$ belongs to the co-domain of $f$ (which is $\mathbb{R}$); so does $s$. That's why $A= f^{-1}(s, \infty)$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But If you look at "Methods of Real Analysis" by Goldberg, In that book f:[a,b] to R but still he has written A = {x: f(x)>s} = f inverse of (s,infinity). Please Check and reply.

Comment: That's what I've written as well. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Now clear. I got the idea